# How to remove shadow behind panel icons in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, panel

I finally got Xubuntu themes working thanks to Xfce Theme Manager, but I am annoyed by this shadow behind panel icons. I would love it to match the panel colour.

Here you see the annoying shadow behind Redshift etc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but there is no way to fix that. That is a part of the panel plugin. You could try going with a darker panel color to make the shadow blend in, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope I helped!

Comment: The shadow disappears if you change from `None(use system style)`to `Solid color` in `Panel > Panel Preferences... > Appearance-Tab`